# PHP including file in CLASS

Tags: php

I want to include file in PHP class.

**Why I want to include file ?**

---

there are too many functions in my class, and its very hard to find them. So I want to put functions in a file by their type, and include them by calling the file in class.

like:
all function for head will be inside a head.php file.

**So please tell me how do I include files in class ?**

Comment: yes it gives error, expecting function

Comment: I totally symphatize with this idea, as I've been in the same spot, but it's not a really clean way of doing OOP. Ideally, the code would be small enough, and split up into separate classes, so that it is still readable. Also many IDEs support code folding which makes navigating through large amounts of code much easier. @Mike it's not possible to use `include()` in a class blueprint

Comment: Is there any class init function, which run when function initialize ?

Comment: Extending classes as @TheNytangel shows above is the only way (that, and of course compiling a giant class file at runtime). It's not really nice though IMO.

Comment: @Pekka - fair enough. I should have tried it first.

Comment: NetBeans and other IDEs can give you a nice menu - sort of like a table of contents - to all the methods in your class, which makes it easy to navigate from one to the other. You can also click inside a method name and then press a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+B in the case of Netbeans) which will take you to where the method was declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you extend the class and put functions in it?

```
class Second extends Main
{

}
```

Comment: the problem is that I am already extending my class, and I cannot change extended class name (restricted by my script)

Comment: Can't you extend an extended class?

Comment: can I?, I tried to do so! but got already exist error

Comment: Did you do `class Third extends Second{}`?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not create a helper class and just include in globally? So you can just call it statically? For example in my application I have a date helper class and whenever I need date function I just use date::currentDay for example. Including is kind of an old concept though. You should really be using autoloading so you include everything up front.